# Paths and geodesics in $SO_n$

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to find some (easily computable) function to interpolate between special orthogonal matrices:

Let $A$, $B$ be $n\times n$ special orthogonal matrices and $0\let\le1$, then $f(A, B, t)$ must return a $n\times n$ special orthogonal matrix such that $f(A, B, 0) = A$, $f(A, B, 1) = B$ and $f$ is smooth as a function of $t$.

In particular, I'm interested in the case where $A = I$.

If possible I would like to avoid computing $O(n)$ decompositions.

Comment: This may not be "easily computable" and explicit, but you could take the line segment $(1-t)A + tB$, and then for each $t$, project onto $\mathrm{SO}_n$ using the Gram-Schmidt algorithm.

Comment: @Nick I'm not sure this works. Consider for instance the matrices $A= I_2$ and $B=-I_2$. For $t=1/2$, you will have some difficulty projecting $0$ onto $SO_n$.

Comment: Right...my suggestion doesn't work if the line segment goes through the origin.

Comment: You can see a matrix of $SO_n$ as an orthonormal basis with the standard orientation. I would try successively rotating the axes into the canonical basis, and then doing the inverse process to reach another matrix.

Comment: @Olivier When $n=3$ that's particularly easy since every orientation preserving rigid motion is a rotation about some axis. Just continuously reduce the angle through which you rotate to $0$ and you're at the identity.

Comment: What do you mean by an "O(n) decomposition"?

Answer (score 1):

A (simple) rotation of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is an element of $SO_n$ that leaves point-wise fixed an $n-2$ dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

**Observation.**
*Every element of $SO_n$ is a product of simple rotations.*

Indeed, let $A \in SO_n$ and denote by $v_1, \dots, v_n$ the columns of $A$. Denote by $R(v_1,e_1)$ the simple rotation of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that maps $v_1$ to $e_1$.
 Then
$$
R(v_1, e_1)A = [e_1 \; \tilde v_2 \; \cdots \: \tilde v_n],
$$
and each $\tilde v_i$ has no component in the direction $e_1$, by orthogonality. By reccurence, you find a sequence $R_1^{-1}, \dots, R_n^{-1}$ of simple rotations such that
$
R_n^{-1} \cdots R_1^{-1} A = I_n.
$
In other words,
$$
A = R_1 \dots R_n I_n.
$$

**Solution.** Now, denote by $R^{\theta}_i$ the rotation that moves the same 2d plane as $R_i$, but by an arbitrary angle $\theta$. You can interpolate between $A$ and $I_n$ by adjusting the angles in the product
$$
R_1^{\theta_1}\dots R_n^{\theta_n}.
$$

**Notes.**

- This method requires computing a decomposition in $n$ matrices. In $\mathbb{R}^3$, as noted by Ethan, you can use a single rotation.
- A better solution would study the geodesics of $SO_n$.